# trigger insert all rows and not only one

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying a  very simple trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_product_size AFTER UPDATE ON tb_product

FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN

        insert  into test_trigger 
                    (product_id,product_size_values) 
            select product_id,product_size_values 
            from tb_product  
            where  product_id = NEW.product_id;

    END
```

but I get 2000 rows and not only the one updated, all the content of tb_product

thanks for helping

Comment: What is the UPDATE query triggering it? `UPDATE x SET y = y WHERE 1=1` technically kinda sort updates every row in `x`, so you may need to use an IF in the trigger to only catch the changes you want.

Comment: when the table tb_product  is updated I want to insert  into test_trigger only  2 fields of the row updated 
there is no "where" clause , only the updated row and nothing else
I Though NEW. will do the job

Comment: Yes, that is clear, but you have to understand that the particular UPDATE query determines which **rows** are updated. `NEW` is the new values of the row updated, but the trigger is fired for every row the update query touched. To determine which field changed you need to test `NEW.somefield <> OLD.somefield`.

Comment: Can you show your UPDATE statement? The trigger looks fine to me. As @Uueerdo mentioned, your UPDATE might touched all the rows.

Comment: thanks ... how do I determine which rows are updated then ?
the database should know itself which row it was

Comment: my update statement is very simple :
UPDATE tb_product SET product_size_vaules = '41' WHERE product_id = 100
I should get  a row in test_trigger = 100 , 41

Comment: If that update triggers 2000 inserts, then product_id is not unique in the tb_product table; or there are update queries coming from somewhere else that you are overlooking.... but technically, you don't actually need the SELECT; you can just use `VALUES (NEW.product_id, NEW.product_size_values)`.

Comment: The 2000 are likely from a different update query, if product_id were not unique the number of rows would be a square, as...  if x rows had 100 for product id, the trigger would fire for each x row, inserting x rows each time, inserting x^2 rows overall. Since 2000 is not a square, we can rule that out.

Comment: @ Uueerdo   the field is product_size_values  if that field change I want to insert that particular row, but IF I do insert  into a_trigger (product_id,product_size_values) select product_id, product_size_values from tb_product   WHERE NEW.product_size_values != OLD.product_size_values ; , same ! I get 2000 rows when only one has changed

Comment: I did not mean using that condition the WHERE... I'll post an answer with what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to catch product_size_values changes; you can do the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_product_size AFTER UPDATE ON tb_product
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (NEW.product_size_values != OLD.product_size_values) THEN 
       INSERT INTO test_trigger (product_id, product_size_values) 
       VALUES (NEW.product_id, NEW.product_size_values)
       ;
   END IF;
END
```